# Group Datatable parent child

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datatable

I have a datatable that shows the links parent child, how can I recreate the same query on c#?, maybe through linq

Example table:

[image: Example table]

SQL Query:

```
  SELECT PARENT,CHILD,max(cnt) as QTY FROM (
  SELECT p.PARENT PARENT,p.CHILD CHILD,row_number () over (partition by P.PARENT,P.CHILD order by P.PARENT desc) as cnt
 FROM [FullParentChild_temp] P
 )t
 GROUP BY PARENT,CHILD
```

Comment: Did you know you can just `SELECT p.PARENT PARENT,p.CHILD CHILD, COUNT(*) over (partition by P.PARENT,P.CHILD) as cnt
 FROM [FullParentChild_temp] P` - no need to number every row in a subquery then get the max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LINQ it looks something like:

```
collection
  .GroupBy(e => new{ e.Parent, e.Child } )
  .Select(g => new { 
    g.Key.Parent, 
    g.Key.Child,
    g.Count()
  });
```

GroupBy doesn't really group in the SQL sense of the word because it preserves the row data. As the result of this group you get something like a dictionary where the item has a Key which is the anonymous type containing the parent and child, and itself (g) is a collection of the values represented by e that had that relevant parent and child combination, of which you want the count

Comment: Thank you for your answer, except that even creating the columns, it gives me back error that e.Parent and e.child, do not exist in context

Comment: You never said what the properties were called in your context; you will have to adjust the code to make the names match. I assumed they were called "Parent" and "Child" because that's what you showed in your grid image

Comment: you understand, in fact I have not specified that my datatable is created automatically by the result of a query on sql

Comment: I'm not really sure, when you say "datatable", whether you're actually talking abut a System.Data.DataTable object, or whether it's just a general term for your results grid. If you're trying to run a LINQ query on a System.Data.DataTable you'll need something like `datatable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().AsQueryable().Select(r => new { Parent = r["Parent"].ToString(), Child = r["Child"].ToString()}).GroupBy..` - they're a bit of a pain in the ass to query to be honest. I'd use a strongly typed datatable, which is much simpler: `stronglyTypedDataTable.GroupBy(...`